# Google OAuth: What do the various fields in id_token stand for?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, openid-connect

The id_token I get at the end of the OAuth exchange has the following:

```
"id_token": {  
   "aud":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "email_verified":true,
   "iss":"accounts.google.com",
   "email":"xxx@gmail.com",
   "iat":1234,
   "exp":1234,
   "azp":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "at_hash":"xxxy",
   "sub":"1243"
}
```

I wanted to know what these stand for? More importantly, which of these fields can I use as a primary key (id)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google adheres to the OpenID Connect standard which defines the `id_token`. So you can find the meaning in that specification here: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken

> iss REQUIRED.
>   Issuer Identifier for the Issuer of the response.
>   The iss value is a case sensitive URL using the https scheme that contains
>   scheme, host, and optionally, port number and path components and no
>   query or fragment components.
>
> sub REQUIRED.
>   Subject Identifier.
>   A locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for
>   the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client, e.g.,
>   24400320 or AItOawmwtWwcT0k51BayewNvutrJUqsvl6qs7A4. It MUST NOT
>   exceed 255 ASCII characters in length. The sub value is a case
>   sensitive string.
>
> aud REQUIRED.
>   Audience(s) that this ID Token is intended for.
>   It MUST contain the OAuth 2.0 client_id of the Relying
>   Party as an audience value. It MAY also contain identifiers for other
>   audiences. In the general case, the aud value is an array of case
>   sensitive strings. In the common special case when there is one
>   audience, the aud value MAY be a single case sensitive string.
>
> exp
>   REQUIRED. Expiration time on or after which the ID Token MUST NOT be
>   accepted for processing.
>   The processing of this parameter requires
>   that the current date/time MUST be before the expiration date/time
>   listed in the value. Implementers MAY provide for some small leeway,
>   usually no more than a few minutes, to account for clock skew. Its
>   value is a JSON number representing the number of seconds from
>   1970-01-01T0:0:0Z as measured in UTC until the date/time. See RFC 3339
>   [RFC3339] for details regarding date/times in general and UTC in
>   particular. iat REQUIRED. Time at which the JWT was issued. Its value
>   is a JSON number representing the number of seconds from
>   1970-01-01T0:0:0Z as measured in UTC until the date/time.
>
> iat REQUIRED.
>   Time at which the JWT was issued.
>   Its value is a JSON number representing the number of seconds from
>   1970-01-01T0:0:0Z as measured in UTC until the date/time.
>
> azp OPTIONAL.
>   Authorized party - the party to which the ID Token was issued.
>   If present, it MUST contain the OAuth 2.0 Client ID of this
>   party. This Claim is only needed when the ID Token has a single
>   audience value and that audience is different than the authorized
>   party. It MAY be included even when the authorized party is the same
>   as the sole audience. The azp value is a case sensitive string
>   containing a StringOrURI value.
>
> at_hash OPTIONAL.
>   Access Token hash value.
>   Its value is the base64url
>   encoding of the left-most half of the hash of the octets of the ASCII
>   representation of the access_token value, where the hash algorithm
>   used is the hash algorithm used in the alg Header Parameter of the ID
>   Token's JOSE Header. For instance, if the alg is RS256, hash the
>   access_token value with SHA-256, then take the left-most 128 bits and
>   base64url encode them. The at_hash value is a case sensitive string.

Furthermore `email` and `email_verified` are standardized claims, found here http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims:

> email string
>   End-User's preferred e-mail address.
>   Its value MUST
>   conform to the RFC 5322 [RFC5322] addr-spec syntax. The RP MUST NOT
>   rely upon this value being unique, as discussed in Section 5.7.
>
> email_verified    boolean
>   True if the End-User's e-mail address has been verified; otherwise false.
>   When this Claim Value is true, this means
>   that the OP took affirmative steps to ensure that this e-mail address
>   was controlled by the End-User at the time the verification was
>   performed. The means by which an e-mail address is verified is
>   context-specific, and dependent upon the trust framework or
>   contractual agreements within which the parties are operating.

So you'll notice that the `sub` is the primary key, which is unique per user over time at least within the scope of the Provider. E-mail is not, because it may be reassigned at some point.